# How do I increase Facebook API's session length?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook's Graph API from Android.

First, what is the default session length (time)?  The ONLY resource I've found stating anything helpful and relevant is from [this Facebook blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/) which suggests the default is 2 hours.

Is there a way to set the session timeout?  If that's the default, one would reason that it can be set.  It'd be great if I could set it for, say, 24 hours.  If it can't be set, do you have a strategy for how you deal with it, without making the user login all the time?  For example, if the session time automatically increases on the server side (say, by 2 hours) with each call to the API, then I'd implement a strategy where I'd call SOME API method every, say, 2-ish hours.

Note that I am aware of the `offline_access` permission.  That seems like overkill.

Comment: Why are you saying `offline_access` is an overkill? If you are going to be interacting while the user is offline anyway (sending API request every 2 hours to keep the session alive), not only are you doing it, but not implicitly making the user aware that you are doing it. They can see from their account when and how often your application has accessed their account and I'm sure they won't be too excited to see it accessing it while they are offline, if your application did not request `offline_access`. If you don't want to store sessions for longer than 24hrs, you could always kill the token.

Comment: You're right.  That would kind of be an 'offline_access' kind of thing.  But making a dummy request to the API actually wouldn't be doing anything (not anything that should alarm a user).  It'd just keep the session alive.  It could be a read-only request, and if they saw it at 2 hour intervals, it probably wouldn't be alarming.